# Back seat latch jammed

Tags: volvo, latch

I have a Volvo 850 and the left back seat latch is jammed. This is the latch that secures the seat in the upright position. Normally, pulling forward on the latch lever releases the latch and the seat can be folded down. Now, the latch is jammed somehow and the lever will not move.

I have tried pulling the seat, jiggling and all kinds of movements but it is stuck fast. There is no access to the latch because it is located at the side of the seat so it is completely covered up when the seat is upright and in the locked position.

How can I unjam the latch?

Comment: A picture would be helpfull

Comment: Have you attempted to remove the seat from the car so you can access the latch mechanism?

Comment: @CharlieRB lol, I actually just had to do that on a Kia this morning to free up a latch.

Comment: @CharlieRB The procedure for removing the back seats in a Volvo 850 requires unlatching the seat.